# Remote web form post in perl

Tags: perl, code-snippets, remote-access

I'm relatively new to perl, I was trying to create a perl script to remote login in a web form and return either sucess or failure. but its not working or i'm missing something, plus it give me an error message: Here is what i wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent; 
use HTTP::Response;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);


$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
$ua->agent("Mozilla 8.0...");

$username = "username";
$password = "password";

my $req = (POST 'http://www.domain.com/login.php', 

["Username" => "$username", 
"Password" => "$password"]);

$request = $ua->request($req); 
$content = $request->content; 

if ($res->is_success) {
     print ("success");
     exit;
}

else {
print ("failure");
}
```

this script is not running at all and the error i'm getting is:

```
Can't call method "is_success" on an undefined value at c:\remotelogin.pl line 24.
```

Comment: Well, you don't have any variable named `$res`, so it kind of makes sense for it to be undefined.

Comment: Downrated because I doubt this question will be of use to anyone else.  If this question were distilled purely to a discussion of this particular error message ("Can't call method X on an undefined value") and the value of `use strict; use warnings;`, it might be more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be stressed enough how important it is to

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Especially when learning perl. In this case, you have an undeclared variable `$res`. Due to a typo perhaps? If you have used strict and warnings, you would have gotten a compilation error:

```
Global symbol "$res" requires explicit package name..
```

Strict and warnings may give a lot of intimidating errors, but once you learn how to avoid them, you realize they save you time and effort rather than the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

`$res` should be replaced with `$request`.

And `use strict; use warnings;`